# Serial communication (for Arduino) using Visual Studio 2008 and C

Tags: c, arduino, serial-communication

I want to send data to my Arduino board using Visual Studio and C.
I specifically need to use C since I am using ARToolKit to get markers and sending the data accordingly.

I was trying the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    system( "MODE COM9: BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 STOP=1" ) ;
    FILE port = fopen( "COM9:", "wb" ) ;
    printf("hello");
    fprintf( port, "s" ) ;
    fclose( port ) ;
}
```

but it is not getting compiled.

I just need to send data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understood from your post that you need to send data using visual studio not to write a program to flash or any other stuff. Here is an example i made for you on my machine it works sending the text test.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char test[] = "Hello";

    HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(L"COM2",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);

    if (hDevice !=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Port opened! \n");
        DCB lpTest;
        GetCommState(hDevice,&lpTest);
        lpTest.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
        lpTest.ByteSize = 8;
        lpTest.Parity = NOPARITY;
        lpTest.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
        SetCommState(hDevice,&lpTest);

        DWORD btsIO;

        WriteFile(hDevice,test,strlen(test),&btsIO,NULL);

        CloseHandle(hDevice);
    }
    _getch();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is a more detalied approach http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/CPPWindows

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is can you communicate to the arduino serial port at all.
If you have XP or earlier it comes with hyperterm, windows vista+7 don't so you need something  like http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/

ps - I'm not sure that the mode parameters created in a system call 'stick' to the calling environment or are reset when the shell exits. See example of [windows serial port programming](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/serial_com.aspx) on how to do it properly

Comment: Thank You, i was using the Serial Monitor provided by the Arduino IDE itself. And yes we can communicate to the arduino serial port but need a UART to TTL converter (eg max232) circuit.

Answer (score 0):

CPPWindows works but it is also in C++. 
For all of you who want to send serial data with OPENCV/ARTOOLKIT or something which is written in C (and not C++).
The code i posted is working now. It required some changes. The final code is:
(Not the change in the COM port)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    FILE* port;
    system( "MODE COM1: BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 STOP=1" ) ;
    port = fopen( "COM1:", "wb" ) ;
    printf("s");
    fprintf( port, "s" ) ;
    fclose( port ) ;
}
```