# Serial communication (for Arduino) using Visual Studio 2010 and C

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, serial-port, arduino

I'm facing a slight issue at the moment. I am currently doing some video (image) detection and tracking using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional and [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV), and the result (of the vision system) is to control additional hardware via the Arduino platform.

My code for the vision system works 100% and code on Arduino also works 100%, but I'm having an issue communicating via C / C++ from the PC to the Arduino board. (Can not use Visual Basic, etc.)

Specifications at the moment: Windows 7 platform, Visual Studio 2010, OpenCV 2.2.0, Arduino 0022, Arduino Mega board, 2 x USB to serial converters for simulations.

My code does not seem to even be functioning. I am, however, following the example below by #opc0de. But to illustrate  my point the code below doesn't seem to work (never states COM open (yes, I change to the write ports)). (Connect two serial cables to each other plugged into two different COM ports hyperterminal, realterm, etc. work 100%. My code and the code below don't seem to work at all). (My code is +- 800 lines long and I don't feel like posting as the COMs section is very similar to below). I just want serial commynication to be working.

***All I want from the COMs is the ability to send a text string, "x=### y=###"  so even a simple piece of code will do (like below) (I want to read at a later stage, but I am not worried it at the moment)***

Link to code: [Stack Overflow - opc0de](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123057/serial-communication-for-arduino-using-visual-studio-2008-and-c)

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char test[] = "Hello";

    HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(L"COM2",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);

    if (hDevice !=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Port opened! \n");
        DCB lpTest;
        GetCommState(hDevice,&lpTest);
        lpTest.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
        lpTest.ByteSize = 8;
        lpTest.Parity = NOPARITY;
        lpTest.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
        SetCommState(hDevice,&lpTest);

        DWORD btsIO;

        WriteFile(hDevice,test,strlen(test),&btsIO,NULL);

        CloseHandle(hDevice);
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Set the handshaking members of DCB.

Comment: Thx Hans, Have set the DCB configs now. Working correctly for this implementation requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code to make sure it works separately:

First, use a COM logger. The old and good Terminal from MS is the worst, but I cannot remember another one right now. See if your C++ code sends something there. If no, make it work :) If yes, debug commnication problems with an Arduino. Make a simple logger on Arduino to see what you receive on the other part and how you handle it.

Comment: Vasile, thanks for the advise a com logger "com  spy" did the trick. Thx.